# I dont know what commands I can use to convert this python script to discord code

Tags: python, discord

StartScore = int(input("What is the score of the person you wish to raid? "))

LowerBound = (StartScore / 1.75)

UpperBound = (StartScore * 1.33333333333)

LowerBound = round(LowerBound, 2)

UpperBound = round(UpperBound, 2)

print ("Only nations with a score of ",LowerBound,"to",UpperBound," can attack them")

Comment: Good code! Works well in python. What are you trying to do with this code on Discord? Are you trying to make a bot on discord that will use this code or just paste the code directly onto a page?

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to make a discord bot that does the same as this code